Add large data to the footer in jsPDF
I want to create a customized footer using jsPDF.
This footer may contain a large amount of data, so I want the content above the footer to automatically flow to the next page.
I am using an auto table to set the footer, but it is not producing the desired results.
autoTable(doc, {
  theme: 'plain',
  tableLineColor: [0, 0, 0],
  tableWidth: 175,
  startY: 277,
  body: [
    [{
      content: (this.orgDetailsObj.terms != undefined ? this.orgDetailsObj.terms : ''),
      styles: {
        halign: 'center',
        valign:'middle',
        fontSize: 8,
        textColor: 'black',
        fillColor:'white',
        // tableLineColor: [0, 0, 0],
        // tableWidth: 100,
        overflow:'linebreak',
      },
    }],
  ]
})

